# Remove the numbers < 4 digits in list in a data frame in R

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame like this this, i need to remove the values less than 4 digits in the item column,

```
department  item
xyz009   c("1","676547","2","434567","3","567369","4","987654","6","54546676732")
```

**Output**

```
department  item

xyz009      676547,434567,567369,987654,54546676732
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please use `dput()` to provide a reproducible example

Comment: Can you make *less than 4 digits or less than 9999*  clearer?

Comment: Maybe the nchar function will be of use

Comment: In your example, you don't have a list, but a vector. You can do what you need with a combination of `xyz009[xyz009>9999]` and `nchar(xyz009)`. For example, `xyz009[xyz009>999 & nchar(xyz009)>4]`

Comment: @RuiBarradas I should remove the values in the item column iif numbers are less than 4 digits

Comment: `df$list <- df$list[nchar(df$list) < 4]`.

Comment: can you make the language more apparent in order to attract better answer.  In the title if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R you can use unlist, and lapply:

```
xyz009<-c("1","676547","2","434567","3","567369","4","987654","6","54546676732")
unlist(lapply(xyz009,function(x) x[nchar(x)>3]))
```

The result is:

```
[1] "676547"      "434567"      "567369"      "987654"      "54546676732"
```

Comment: Thanks @SSD93 I dont need unlist here. I have applied till lapply It worked !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `nchar`+`subset`

```
> subset(v,nchar(v)>4)
[1] "676547"      "434567"      "567369"     
[4] "987654"      "54546676732"
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c("1","676547","2","434567","3","567369","4","987654","6","54546676732")
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

```
xyz009 <- c("1","676547","2","434567","3","567369","4","987654","6","54546676732")
```

2.Suggested solution using base R:

The vector `xyz009` is of type `character`

```
typeof(xyz009)

[1] "character"
```

In order to do maths with it (i.e. use `>`) we have to cast it to numeric using `as.numeric`

```
num_xyz <- as.numeric(xyz009)
```

Now we can use an index to 'filter' values where an expression evaluates to `TRUE`:

```
test_result <- num_xyz > 9999
```

The vector `test_result` consists of booleans

```
test_result

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

We can use these booleans as an 'index' (R keeps only values where the index is `TRUE`):

```
num_xyz[test_result]
```

This returns:

```
[1]      676547      434567      567369      987654 54546676732
```